# Macro often crashes when it emails reports via Outlook

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I  use a scheduled task to run an Access 2007 macro to email via Outlook, multiple Access reports in notepad, Excel 2003 and html formats.  around 50% of the time, the Access app crashes and automatically restarts and repairs itself and creates a backup … What can I do prevent the app from crashing?

I don’t know if it is relevant to the problem or not , but the only VBA in the app is to prevent the macro  from emailing empty reports, if there are zero records in the report’s data-source query. I set this up in the reports’ properties/event/  “on no-data”/even procedure 
 (Option Compare Database

Private Sub Report_NoData(Cancel As Integer)

End Sub)

Thank you very much in advance for your help, Nathaniel

Comment: Well, first of all you have no code in your NoData event. 2nd of all, if we could see the rest of your code that does the e-mailing, that may help.

Answer (score 1):

Is it failing when your repor doesn't have data? In the NoData event, you need to set Cancel=True so that the report stops if there's no data.  The code that opens the report needs to trap for that error and handle it accordingly (not send the email).

Sending emails via Outlook can be troublesome with the MAPI security issues. I use the add-in Total Access Emailer from FMS to automate my emails from Access. It lets you attach reports to your messages filtered for each person in the list: http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Email.asp

Hope that helps.

Comment: The app fails even when there is no data in the reports (the macro runs 10 different reports consecutively).  I did a controlled test, by removing the no-data event code from all of the reports , but the app still crashes just as frequently without the code. There doesn’t seem to be any one specific report that is causing the app to crash, because sometimes the app crashes as soon as the app opens, before the first report is even outputted and other times the app crashes after outputting one of the other reports, without any specific pattern. please advise

Comment: I changed the macro's output format to PDF for all 10 of the reports and now the app seems to run without crashing. Does anyone know why the output macro's format can casue the app to crash?